# How can I customize SliverAppBar Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-sliver, sliverappbar, flutter-sliverappbar

Hi Guys I locking for create app bar Like this with `SliverAppBar()` widget Like this :

[image]

And I Tried to make it With `SliverAppBar()` But The output is like this :

[image]

Here is Code :

```
Scaffold(
            drawer: const Drawer(),
            body: CustomScrollView(
              slivers: [
                SliverAppBar(
                  pinned: true,
                  elevation: 0,
                  backgroundColor: Colors.grey.shade200,
                  title: Text(
                    "All notes",
                    style: AppStyle.normalTextStyle
                        .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                  ),
                  actions: [
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: () => Get.to(() => SearchBar(notes: notes)),
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.search)),
                    IconButton(
                        onPressed: () {},
                        icon: const Icon(Icons.more_vert_outlined))
                  ],
                  expandedHeight: 200,
                  flexibleSpace: Column(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                    children: [
                      const SizedBox(height: 80),
                      Text(
                        "All notes",
                        style: AppStyle.largeTextStyle
                            .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w600),
                      ),
                      const SizedBox(height: 10),
                      Text(
                        "${notes.length} notes",
                        style: AppStyle.smallTextStyle
                            .copyWith(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),

                ),
                SliverToBoxAdapter(
                  child: Padding(
                      padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 16),
                      child: GridView.builder(
                        scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                        shrinkWrap: true,
                        primary: false,
                        gridDelegate:
                            const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                          mainAxisExtent: 170,
                          crossAxisCount: 2,
                        ),
                        itemCount: notes.length,
                        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                          final note = notes[index];
                          return GestureDetector(
                              onTap: () =>
                                  Get.to(() => DetailsScreen(id: note.id)),
                              child: BaseContainer(note: note));
                        },
                      )),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            floatingActionButton: SizedBox(
              height: 65,
              width: 65,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                tooltip: 'Add note',
                child: const Icon(
                  Icons.add,
                  size: 30,
                ),
                onPressed: () => Get.to(() => const AddScreen()),
              ),
            ),
          );
```

So how can I reverse `SliverAppBar()` when it's scrolling just like a first video ?
and second question is how can I remove that `All notes` text when it's scrolling and replace it with Large one just like first Video ..

if it possible to create that appBar like the first video (Samsung notes appBar) except `SliverAppBar()` please let me know .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: Result]

Please refer to the below code

```
class _AnimatedAppBarState extends State<AnimatedAppBar>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  final TextEditingController stateController = TextEditingController();
  final FocusNode stateFocus = FocusNode();

  var animation;
  var controller;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
        body: NestedScrollView(
          headerSliverBuilder:
              (BuildContext context, bool innnerBoxIsScrolled) {
            if (innnerBoxIsScrolled) {
              /* Animation */
              controller = AnimationController(
                vsync: this,
                duration: Duration(
                  seconds: 1,
                ),
              );
              animation = Tween(
                begin: 0.0,
                end: 1.0,
              ).animate(controller);
              /* Animation */
              controller.forward();
            }
            return <Widget>[
              SliverAppBar(
                expandedHeight: 120.0,
                floating: false,
                pinned: true,
                backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,
                automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
                titleSpacing: 0.0,
                toolbarHeight:
                    (innnerBoxIsScrolled != null && innnerBoxIsScrolled == true)
                        ? 60.0
                        : 160.0,
                centerTitle: false,
                elevation: 0.0,
                leadingWidth: 0.0,
                title: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    if (innnerBoxIsScrolled != null &&
                        innnerBoxIsScrolled == true)
                      FadeTransition(
                        opacity: animation,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              height: 5.0,
                            ),
                            Row(
                              children: [
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 5.0,
                                ),
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.menu,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 10.0,
                                ),
                                Text(
                                  "All Notes",
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    color: Colors.black,
                                  ),
                                ),
                                Spacer(),
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.search,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                                SizedBox(
                                  width: 10.0,
                                ),
                                Icon(
                                  Icons.more_vert,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                  ],
                ),
                flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                  background: Container(
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 30.0,
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "All Notes",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 24.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "2 Notes",
                          style: TextStyle(
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                            fontSize: 24.0,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Spacer(),
                        Row(
                          children: [
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 5.0,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.menu,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            Spacer(),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.search,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                            SizedBox(
                              width: 10.0,
                            ),
                            Icon(
                              Icons.more_vert,
                              color: Colors.black,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                        SizedBox(
                          height: 10.0,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ];
          },
          body: Builder(
            builder: (BuildContext context) {
              return SingleChildScrollView(
                child: Column(
                  children: [
                    ListView.builder(
                      itemCount: 100,
                      physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                      shrinkWrap: true,
                      itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(4.0),
                          child: Text("Index value: $index"),
                        );
                      },
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              );
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";
void main()=>runApp(MyApp());
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: "SliverAppBar",
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.red,
      ),
      home: Home(),
    );
  }
}
class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  bool x=true;
  bool y=true;
  bool z=true;
  void xxx(){
    setState(() {
      x=!x;
    });
  }
  void yyy(){
    setState(() {
      y=!y;
    });
  }
  void zzz(){
    setState(() {
      z=!z;
    });
  }
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverAppBar(
            centerTitle: z,
            pinned: x,
            floating: y,
            expandedHeight: 150.0,
            flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
              title: Text("CodeCave"),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.fiber_pin),tooltip: "Pinned",onPressed: xxx,),
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.flare),tooltip: "Floating",onPressed: yyy,),
              IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.center_focus_strong),tooltip: "Center Text",onPressed: zzz,),
            ],
          ),
          SliverFillRemaining(
            child: Center(
              child: Text("DEMO"),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```