# How can i create appBar which visible when i scroll to a specific widget in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation, flutter-appbar

[See, the header is transparent with just a back leading icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/312cA.png)
[See how the header changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yagVJ.png)

I want to achieve the same effect.
If i could add a transition between the two app bars that would be even better!

I have tried using "SliverAppBar" but if I add a leading back button in app bar, it stays there in the title!

[See the arrow button and if I add action button it will also be visible](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8rJ8l.png)

[I only want the arrow to be visible here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jeZWQ.png)

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/73118479/15215450

Answer (score 0):

You can use sliver app bar provided by flutter inside custom scroll view. You can find example [here](https://medium.com/@diegoveloper/flutter-collapsing-toolbar-sliver-app-bar-14b858e87abe) and flutter documentation [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliverAppBar-class.html)

Comment: I cant get the desired result :(